# Generated codelab does not work. Files removed from storage.googleapis.com

Tags: google-codelab

I have been using codelabs for creating tutorials.
https://github.com/googlecodelabs

I use the claat tool to generate the tutorial from an md file.

Since the past few days I have noticed my codelabs have stopped rendering.
It appears like the css and js files which were served through storage.googleapis.com are removed. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Tried accessing the css and js files directly
https://storage.googleapis.com/codelab-elements/codelab-elements.css
It gives an error

Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage
object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

I know this is the problem but dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issues

There is a fix for both the template
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/pull/798/commits/c9e6704bec43413dc972dd17d48df59589d4b2cb#diff-32ca476fba2e5a4abb3a8851cdd88e3f115676a9bce40a587c4d0d3e6a644341

as well a new claat version https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/releases/tag/v2.2.5.

In my own claat template I have adjusted the links to all my ressources like ccs and js from /codelab-elements/.. to /claat-public/..  and that fixed the issue.